# does github's GraphQL API deprecate the rest api?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm starting a brand new project (aka no legacy code) that will interact with github, and there's currently 2 supported APIs, the "rest" API is called "API V3" and the "GraphQL" API is called "API V4",

question is then, does the V4 API deprecate the V3 API? Should I strive to use the V4 API even if I think the V3 API seems easier to use? or should I just pick the API that seems like the best fit regardless of the API version number?

Comment: And interesting to note that they're about to deprecate graphQL for some uses and go back to Rest:
https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-18-deprecation-notice-graphql-for-packages/

Comment: @MarkAdamson interesting! i predict that the V3 api will be supported longer than the V4 api then (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two stable versions of the GitHub API: the REST API v3 and the GraphQL API v4.

Looking at the https://developer.github.com/v3/versions/ - it is not. Only V1 and V2 are listed in the "deprecated" section - both are already dead since 2012.